# Jquery not working in Coffeescript function Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm new to coffee script, so forgive me if this is a simple problem.

I'm trying to make a simple class change when a specific view is loaded in Rails.  Specifically I want to run:

$(#mydiv).addClass('active')

In my coffee script, I have the following:

```
class MyApp.Sessions extends MyApp.Base
  constructor:() ->
    super  # call Base class for core functionality
    this   # and be sure to return this

  index:() -> 
    $ -> 
        $('#mydiv').addClass('active')
```

but the resulting javascript ends up placing my Jquery command outside of the function:

```
Sessions.prototype.index = function() {
  return $(function() {});
};

$('#mydiv').addClass('active');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: no it does not: http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20MyApp.Sessions%20extends%20MyApp.Base%0A%20%20constructor%3A()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20super%20%20%23%20call%20Base%20class%20for%20core%20functionality%0A%20%20%20%20this%20%20%20%23%20and%20be%20sure%20to%20return%20this%0A%0A%20%20index%3A()%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%24%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24('%23mydiv').addClass('active')

Answer (score 1):

This seems really complicated.  If you only want to set a class when a page is loaded, then the answer depends on if you're using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) from Rails 4.

With turbolinks, you could just hook into the `page:load` event like

```
document.on 'page:load', () ->
  $('#mydiv').addClass 'active'
```

Comment: I really don't like turbolinks (for many reasons, which I won't discuss here), so I'm looking for a way to do page-specific loading.

Comment: If you're not using turbolinks, then you can just put a script tag in your view itself that does document.ready(function() {$('#mydiv').addClass('active');};

Comment: I'd like to avoid inline scripts in my view, as it will not be precompiled in the assets, and slows down page loading

Comment: If you put the script at the bottom and use document.ready(function() {...}); then it shouldn't really slow down the page load.  It's a pretty minimal amount of code to worry about precompiling, but YMMV.